# What is the difference between \fontsize{...}{some length} and \linespread{some length}?

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I notice that the second argument to `\fontsize` and the first argument to `\linespread` both seem to change the spacing between lines of text. What is the difference between these? Is there one I should favor using?

Comment: Just as a general remark: The [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package is usually considered the best way to influence line spacing. Iirc, some of the reasons are that it doesn't mess up lists (which are in more places than you would expect!) and it leaves the footnotes untouched, which is usually desired.

Comment: There is also the [`leading`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leading) package

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The argument to `\linespread` is a real number (not a length), while both arguments to `\fontsize` are lengths.

`\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}` sets the font `<size>` and `<baselineskip>`, while `\linespread{<factor>}` is used as a *multiple* for the `\baselineskip`. In fact, the latter is virtually equivalent to

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{<factor>}
```

It's your choice which to use. However, both require a font selection on order to be activated. Read more on this peculiarity in the TeX FAQ entry [Why doesn’t `\linespread` work?](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-linespread)

In the LaTeX kernel, `\fontsize` and `\linespread` is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\linespread[1]
   {\set@fontsize{#1}\f@size\f@baselineskip}
\DeclareRobustCommand\fontsize[2]
   {\set@fontsize\baselinestretch{#1}{#2}}
```

Note that both utilize `\set@fontsize{<factor>}{<size>}{<baselineskip>}`. The reason for separating the two allows you to use a fix the one while manipulating the other. Once `\set@fontsize` is called, it creates `\size@update` that sets `\baselineskip` as a `\baselinestretch` multiple of itself and stores this result in `\normalbaselineskip` for other uses (amongst other things). A call to `\selectfont` "uses" these settings. For the wild at heart, here's the nitty gritty (with some comments):

```
\def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
    \@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil
    \edef\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}% <-- extracts font size
    \@defaultunits\@tempskipa#3pt\relax\@nnil
    \edef\f@baselineskip{\the\@tempskipa}% <-- extracts baseline skip
    \edef\f@linespread{#1}% <-- extracts baseline stretch
    \let\baselinestretch\f@linespread% <-- stores baseline stretch
      \def\size@update{%
        \baselineskip\f@baselineskip\relax% <-- stores baseline skip in \baselineskip
        \baselineskip\f@linespread\baselineskip% <-- multiplies \baselineskip by \baselinestretch
        \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip% <-- stores \normalbaselineskip
        \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
          \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
                \@depth.3\baselineskip
                \@width\z@}%
        \let\size@update\relax}%
  }
```

All these intricacies are meant to be simplified through [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) for consistency.

Comment: It seems that using both of them has a compounding effect; is one used in calculation of the other or something?